# DEFLATE discrepancy?

Tags: python, lua, zlib, deflate

So I'm trying to create a python script to generate a level for a game made in MMF2+Lua, and I've run into something I can't figure out how to fix.
Generating a 16x16 empty level with borders with the game gives this (deflated):
`78 5E 63 20 0A FC 27 00 40 86 8C AA C1 1D 02 23 3D 7C 08 27 32 00 9F 62 FE 10`
which should be a flattened 18x18 array with the edge having `0x00`, and the rest having `0xFF`.
My python script generates this with the exact same input to `zlib.deflate`:
`78 9C 63 60 20 06 FC 27 00 46 D5 8C AA C1 A7 86 30 00 00 9F 62 FE 10`
They're different, but inflating them gives the same exact data. However, when I put the data into the game, it crashes when trying to load the level.
What's really different between the two values, and am I able to fix it?

Comment: Please post the Python script you're using to deflate and inflate them.

Comment: I've figured it out, but I can't mark as answered yet. Somewhere else in the metadata, it was swapping some bits I was unaware of. It works now. Even still, I'm wondering what _is_ different between them?

Comment: You can write an answer to your own question, and then accept the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Those are two different encodings of the same data, both valid. They differ in the sequence of copies. Here are readable forms of both, first from the game:

```
! infgen 2.6 output
!
zlib
!
last
fixed
literal 0
match 37 1
literal 255
match 31 1
match 4 69
match 258 36
match 26 258
match 256 288
match 34 613
end
!
adler
```

then from zlib:

```
! infgen 2.6 output
!
zlib
!
last
fixed
literal 0 0
match 36 1
literal 255
match 31 1
match 258 36
match 258 36
match 28 36
match 34 1
end
!
adler
```

`literal` gives a byte or bytes inserted in the stream. `match` is a copy of previous bytes in the stream (possibly overlapped with bytes being copied), where the first parameter is the number of bytes to copy, and the second parameter is the distance back in bytes to copy from.

Comment: You aren't, by any chance, Mark Adler as in the author of the Adler-32 checksum algorithm?

Comment: I am...........